# Using SBT to generate two Jar one with code and resources and other with dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using sbt as a build tool in my scala project.
Currently we are shipping code using `sbt-assembly` and the size of this jar is over 1GB.

I want to use `sbt-package` which will help reduce the size of the jar as the first jar (Which will contain my code and resources)
, another jar with all dependencies that can be used as a parameter to run my application (Best way to create a single jar out of these dependicies).

How do I achieve this?.

Comment: have you looked at [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/index.html)? I'm not sure what you're app is, but they have many archetypes for common scenarios eg:  [java command line apps](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/index.html). Might be a better fit for creating an app archive.